# How can I pass in a Function to another Function with an optional parameter set in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `Activation` class.

```dart
class Activation {
  static double Sigmoid(double x, { bool derivative = false }) {
    if (!derivative) {
      return 1 / (1 + exp(-x));
    }
    return x * (1 - x);
  }
```

I want to know how can I pass the above function into another function with that `derivative` flag set to `true`.

```dart
outputs.map(Activation.Sigmoid);
```

In the above line the `derivative` flag will be in `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `Sigmoid` function in another closure and provide a value for `derivative` that way:

```dart
outputs.map((e) => Activation.Sigmoid(e, derivative: true));
```